# LibGDX rendering : FPS gets slow at regular interval

Tags: java, libgdx

I use LibGDX and render a tile set on the screen and (quite) everything goes fine (rendering time about 6ms).
The problem is that at a regular interval (and for a duration of one frame), the FPS becomes very low (rendering time of more than 200ms), and I can't point out what happens. 
Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
for(int l = 0; l < _mapLayers.getCount(); ++l)
        {
            MapLayer layer = _mapLayers.get(l);
            if(layer instanceof TiledMapTileLayer)
            {
                TiledMapTileLayer tileLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer)layer;
                for(int yy = 0; yy < tileLayer.getHeight(); ++yy)
                {
                    int y = tileLayer.getHeight() - yy - 1;
                    for(int x = 0; x < tileLayer.getWidth(); ++x)
                    {
                        Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(mapX + x * _tileW, mapY + yy * _tileH, _tileW, _tileH);
                        if(tileRect.overlaps(visibleBounds))
                        {
                            Cell cell = tileLayer.getCell(x, y);
                            if(cell != null)
                            {
                                TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();
                                float tx = mapX + x * _tileW;
                                float ty = mapY + yy * _tileH;
                                _batch.draw(_tileRegions.get(tile.getId()), tx, ty);
                                ++n;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there someone having an idea of what the problem could be ?

Comment: Sounds like you're experiencing problems with the garbage collection. Make sure to remove all calls with `new` keyword.

Comment: In fact the way I was testing visibility of the tiles on the screen was the problem (with `new Rectangle(...)`). I computed the boundaries of the rectangle to be displayed before rendering the tile set and it works like a charm now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: change the line `Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(...` as @Xoppa mentiond. Create one Rect which you change instead of creating tons of new ones. Imagin if you have a 100x50 tiledmap you create at least 5000 rects(every call) which need to be cleaned. If you create one per call and change it you should have the problems.

Comment: Sure. I was just testing and didn't think about that. Thanks :)